# what's the webpack's mechanism to determine which part of package should be include

Tags: javascript, webpack, redux-saga

## situations:

1. I'm using redux-saga package.
2. I have two package A and B . And both of them depend on **redux-saga** package.
3. I'm building a new project which depends on A, B, and also **redux-saga**.
4. I'm using webpack to make a bundle for my new project.

## expecting:

The bundle of my new project should include redux-saga only once.

## reality:

If I import part of redux-saga's package in A and B package by:

```
import {take, ...} from 'redux-saga/effect'
```

then every things works as expected.  redux-saga's code only included one times in my bundle.

But, if I import some part of redux-saga by this way in A and B package:

```
import {End, ...} from 'redux-saga'
```

Then, the redux-saga's code will be duplicate 3 times in my bundle

## question

How does this comes ? And how can I improve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be that I had ran **npm link** for package A and B. If I install A and B in normal approach then every thing works as expected!